# Usar dados do arquivo no código php

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como modificar tal código para que ele leia os dados do arquivo `.txt` para realizar a busca a partir deles.

Código:

```
<?php

function dijkstra($graph_array, $source, $target) {
    $vertices = array();

    $neighbours = array();
    foreach ($graph_array as $edge) {
        array_push($vertices, $edge[0], $edge[1]);
        $neighbours[$edge[0]][] = array("end" => $edge[1], "cost" => $edge[2]);
        $neighbours[$edge[1]][] = array("end" => $edge[0], "cost" => $edge[2]);
    }
    $vertices = array_unique($vertices);
 echo $vertices[5]."<br>";
    foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
        $dist[$vertex] = INF;
        $previous[$vertex] = NULL;
    }

    $dist[$source] = 0;
    $Q = $vertices;
    while (count($Q) > 0) {

        // TODO - Find faster way to get minimum
        $min = INF;
        foreach ($Q as $vertex){
            if ($dist[$vertex] < $min) {
                $min = $dist[$vertex];
                $u = $vertex;
                echo $u;
            }
        }

        $Q = array_diff($Q, array($u));
        if ($dist[$u] == INF or $u == $target) {
            break;
        }

        if (isset($neighbours[$u])) {
            foreach ($neighbours[$u] as $arr) {
                $alt = $dist[$u] + $arr["cost"];
                if ($alt < $dist[$arr["end"]]) {
                    $dist[$arr["end"]] = $alt;
                    $previous[$arr["end"]] = $u;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $path = array();
    $u = $target;
    while (isset($previous[$u])) {
        array_unshift($path, $u);
        $u = $previous[$u];
    }
    array_unshift($path, $u);
    return $path;
}

$graph_array = array(
                    array("a", "b", 7),
                    array("a", "c", 9),
                    array("a", "f", 14),
                    array("b", "c", 10),
                    array("b", "d", 15),
                    array("c", "h", 11),
                    array("c", "f", 2),
                    array("d", "e", 6),
                    array("e", "f", 9),
                    array("f", "h", 7),
                    array("h", "i", 3)
               );

$path = dijkstra($graph_array, "a", "i");

echo "path is: ".implode(", ", $path)."\n";

?>
```

Arquivo txt:

```
city=A(100,80);
city=B(160,70);
city=C(110,50);
city=D(140,120);
city=F(155,40);
city=G(210,60);
city=H(190,10);
city=I(170,110);
route=A-C;140;
route=A-D;155;
route=C-F;125;
route=D-B;115;
route=D-I;152;
route=B-F;119;
route=B-G;136;
route=G-F;133;
route=F-H;163;
route=I-H;197;
```

Comment: Seria importante [edit] a postagem e mostrar como tentou fazer, e qual foi a etapa que teve dificuldade, assim facilita para quem for responder.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, quer colocar o código de *leitura de arquivo*, isso?

Comment: Sim, colocar a leitura de arquivo ao invés de digitar o que desejo pesquisar!

Comment: @LuizFelipe Você quer passar somente as "rotas" que estão no arquivo para essa função? as "cidades" não? outra coisa, por exemplo, na última linha você quer pegar `I`, `H` e *197* separadamente ou a linha inteira?

Comment: @stderr Eu quero tanto as "rotas" quanto as "cidades"! Sendo que os valores que se encontram ao lado das cidades e das rotas são para realizar o cálculo para determinar a menor distância!

Comment: @LuizFelipe Ok.. no caso das "cidades", você quer pegar a letra e os dois números separados por `,` certo? e "rotas" você quer pegar as letras separadas por `-` e o número, correto?

Comment: @stderr Está correto !

Comment: @stderr Pensei que eu tinha avaliado aquele dia, sinto muito! Sim sim, funcionou da maneira que eu necessitava! E mais uma vez, sinto muito por não ter dado um feedback antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ler o conteúdo do arquivo de texto, você pode usar o [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$linhas = file_get_contents('mapa.txt');
```

Para pegar os dados que você quer, use o método [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all("~(?:city|route)=(\w+)(?:\(|\-)(\w+)(?:\,|\;)(\w+)~", $linhas, $pontos);
```

A variável `pontos` vai conter os resultados obtidos da expressão `(?:city|route)=(\w+)(?:\(|\-)(\w+)(?:\,|\;)(\w+)` que vai corresponder a letras e números seguidos de `(` ou `-`, letras ou números seguidos de `,` ou `;` e letras e números seguidos de `)` ou `;`. Teste a expressão [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/rV2lS2/1).

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/6dVzBO)</kbd>

```
city=A(100,80);
city=B(160,70);
route=A-C;140;
route=A-D;155;
```

Supondo que o arquivo tenha os dados acima, o resultado vai ser:

- `$pontos[1]`: *A, B, A, A*,
- `$pontos[2]`: *100, 160, C, D*
- `$pontos[3]`: *80, 70, 140, 155*